# -ERR POP3 is available only with SSL or TLS connection enabled

Tags: c#, ssl, pop3, tls

Подскажите кто знает. Уже несколько дней мучаюсь с попыткой подключиться к серверу pop.mail.ru по 110 порту. При отправке USER получаю ошибку от сервера:

```
-ERR POP3 is available only with SSL or TLS connection enabled
```

В интернете все примеры не рассчитаны на то, что будет использоваться шифрование SSL или TLS, как подключиться с этим шифрованием? Может статьи какие нибудь есть? Спасибо за ответ.

Код:

```
mailclient = new TcpClient("pop.mail.ru", 110);
NetworkStream ns = mailclient.GetStream();
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ns);
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ns);

sw.WriteLine("USER " + "***@mail.ru");
sw.Flush();
```

Comment: А какой класс используется для этого? Как подключаетесь? Где код то?

Comment: @Oleg  добавил код

Comment: *"В интернете все примеры не рассчитаны"* -- да ладно! Простейший запрос в гугл выдаёт десятки примеров. Даже я, не видевший Windows много лет, за несколько секунд нашёл как использовать класс `SslStream`...

Comment: @PinkTux, Угу) Что-то реально проблему у людей с поиском)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно использовать `SslStream` вместе с `TcpClient`, а затем использовать `SslStream` для чтения данных, а не `TcpClient`.

Что-то вроде:

```
    TcpClient mail = new TcpClient();
    SslStream sslStream;
    int bytes = -1;

    mail.Connect("pop.mail.ru", 995);
    sslStream = new SslStream(mail.GetStream());

    sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient("pop.mail.ru");

    byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
    // Чтение потока, чтобы убедиться, что мы подключены
    bytes = sslStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytes));

    //Отправить имя пользователя для входа в систему
    sslStream.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("USER USER_EMAIL\r\n"));
    bytes = sslStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytes));

    //Отправить пароль для входа в систему                       
    sslStream.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("PASS USER_PASSWORD\r\n"));
    bytes = sslStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytes));

    //Получить первое письмо 
    sslStream.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("RETR 1\r\n"));
    bytes = sslStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytes));
```

Взято [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8375013/how-to-use-ssl-in-tcpclient-class)

Comment: Спасибо, проблема была в том что я пытался все это сделать в потоке Background. Я разбираюсь с C# только второй день, могли бы Вы посоветовать хорошие ресурсы по обучению этому языку?

Comment: @Denis 
http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/137598683/ https://vk.com/page-54530371_48778461